# To optimize the query performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

i have stored procedure which returns like minimum of 40K rows and it takes like 20 seconds in SSMS 2008 R2 where the database resides in Sql Azure but when i run the same Sp in my c# application using EF 5 or  just Normal ADo.NET it took like 70-80 seconds.

table has a non-clustered index on ScenarioID

Sp is just a select statement with where condition.      `select * from Cost where ScenarioID= @ID`

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetActCostsByID", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DateTime timee = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine(timee);
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                timee = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine(timee);
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to increase the performance:

My execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: Do you have `Index` in `Id` column

Comment: If the table is Huge you cannot expect the results to be fast.

Comment: How long does it take to iterate through the result without loading into the data table?

Comment: Id run this through the profiler, just to check if its executing the appropriate query plan, and not doing something strange like a full table scan

Answer (score 1):

Your nonclustered index on `ScenarioID` might not be helping, if you're not `INCLUDE`ing all the columns you're trying to return, as it will need to do lookups to get those other columns - if there are lots of rows for that Scenario, you could end up with an ordinary table scan. And this comes down to statistics, so can vary from server to server.

If you can avoid the need for lookups, you'll get more consistent performance.

Comment: It doesn't looks like OP's problem has it's origin in database, because he have specified clearly: "it takes like 20 seconds in SSMS", and 70 seconds from his app. So problem should be on C# side.

Comment: I have included all the columns in the Index

Comment: @Andy - right, but a different plan can appear if the index is not ideal.

Comment: @Vivekh - check the plans that are being used. It sounds like they must be different

Comment: In SSMS its using the plan appropriate plan which is using the specified index

Comment: But is it using the appropriate plan when called from C#

Comment: Vivekh - can you post the plan here?

Comment: That's the tool tip from the Seek Operator... What other operators are there?